# How to include a view conditionally in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rendering, ejs

I only want to show **dashboard** in my ***ejs template*** when my session variable `person` is not `null` or not `undefined`.

But it's just showing the dashboard every time. and in my log statement, the `person` value is `undefined`.

```
<%= console.log(person); %>
<% if (person !== null || person !== undefined) { %>
<%- include("dashboard"); %>
<% } else { %>
<%- include("login"); %>
<% } %>
```

What could be the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but can you try changing the if statement to

```
<% if (person) { %>
```

It will simple return true if person is not null or undefined

Comment: well if the person is equal to an empty string, then the if statement also evaluating to true. Actually, the error has been found it was to use the && instead of ||, Thanks Mate

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following way:

`<%- include(person !== null && person !== undefined ? "dashboard" : "login"); %>`